# Rails MD5 mismatch on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.2 app in production. Recently (unfortunately, I don't know exactly when) it was pointed out to me that some of the images were broken: the server was returning 404s for them. I confirmed that this was the case for some images both in the markup and referenced in the CSS file.

If I try to load the image by itself, say, https://www.navigatingcancer.com/assets/screenshots/discussions_groups-8d04988b189bf9093348b8246ad5f4b7.png, it 404s. However, if I remove the MD5 fingerprint, the image loads.

When I SSH into production and run

`helper.asset_path('screenshots/discussions_groups.png')`

I get

`/assets/screenshots/discussions_groups-3c30cbd76d94e13f6c6c6a1712cbedc5.png`

Notice this fingerprint is different than the one referenced by the markup above. And indeed, *this* URL and fingerprint load as expected if I place it in the URL.

It appears as though Rails is serving an outdated MD5 fingerprint for this image in the code.

Note that images are the only assets this is affected by, not stylesheets or JS files. Also, the images have not changed.

#### What I've Tried

- I cleared the cache on my browser.
- I checked our staging environment. Though the fingerprints differ, the images load correctly.
- We were using the `turbo_sprockets` gem, which I thought might have something to do with it, but I took it out of our `Gemfile` and redeployed. The hashes must've been regenerated, because different images were broken this time around.
- I read [this thread on rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2569). Apparently, hashes will differ in different environments, so that explains why they're not broken on staging. But not why they are broken on production.
- I ssh'ed into production again and ran `find . -name discussions_groups*`, and it found the one referenced in `asset_path` above (i.e., the one with the valid hash), but not the one referenced in the markup.
- During this SSH session, I `grep`ed for `discussions_groups`, and the version referenced in the `public/assets/manifest.yml` is the one with the valid hash.

*Note: I recognize that this might have to do with my production environment, but I'm hoping that I've made an error general enough that the answer can be helpful to others.*

Comment: Since you didn't say you've tried it:  `rake assets:clobber` followed by `rake assets:precompile` may alleviate the situation.  Use with care, maybe back up the assets dir first since it's production.

Comment: This is Rails 3, so I don't have `clobber`, but I tried `rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile` on staging. This worked in the sense that all the images loaded, but they had previously, so it's hard to tell if there was a change. There were about 4 minutes of sporadic asset failures, so I probably can't do that on prod until there's a maintenance window.

Comment: I believe `rake assets:clobber` just runs `rm -rf public/assets`.  It's very much a brute force approach.  It depends on your situation which is worse:  continuing to have these assets 404 or a few minutes of downtime.  Hopefully someone else will come by with a more elegant solution.